# mongodb change stream resume from timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In mongodb docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/
there is a quote:

> The oplog must have enough history to locate the operation associated with the token or the timestamp, if the timestamp is in the past.

So it seems that it is possible to resume and get all the events that where added to oplog from a certain time.

There is a param, seems that it has to accomplish what I need

```
watch([],{startAtOperationTime: ...})
```

https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/change-streams/change-streams.rst#startatoperationtime

Param is Timestamp, I don't get how to translate a particular date to correct timestamp.

Comment: I believe "timestamp" mentioned in the docs are misleading here. It's not a regular timestamp, but rather oplog-specific timestamp. To be able to resume a changestream, you would need to use the supplied resume token (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resume-tokens)

Comment: Than what is https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/change-streams/change-streams.rst#startatoperationtime in spec? And it is stated that startAtOperationTime, resumeAfter, and startAfter are all mutually exclusive;

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[startAtOperationTime](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/change-streams/change-streams.rst#id18) is a new parameter for changestreams introduced in MongoDB 4.0 and newer driver versions. It allows you to ensure that you're not missing any writes just in case the stream was interrupted, and you don't have access to the resume token.

One caveat of using `startAtOperationTime` is that your app needs to be prepared to accept that it may see a write event twice when resuming the changestream, since you're resuming from an arbitrary point in time.

In node, this can be done by constructing a [Timestamp object](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Timestamp.html) and passing it into [watch()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#watch):

```
async function run() {
  const con = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true})
  const ts = new Timestamp(1, 1560812065)
  con.db('test').collection('test').watch([], {startAtOperationTime: ts})
    .on('change', console.log)
}
```

The `Timestamp` object itself is created with the form of:

```
new Timestamp(ordinal, unix_epoch_in_seconds)
```

A detailed explanation can be found in [BSON Timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps).

In node, you can get the current epoch (in milliseconds) using e.g.:

```
(new Date).getTime()
```

bearing in mind that this needs to be converted to seconds for creating the `Timestamp` object needed for `startAtOperationTime`.

Comment: This actually don't work for me, I don't get past events, did you check? Maybe the problem with nodejs driver (I tried the latest version), Mongodb 4.0?

Comment: Ah it works in the latest driver 3.3-beta version. Thanks.